# How to add GIF loader in Webpack config with Typescript/React/Nextjs app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, web, webpack, next.js

I am getting error after I added `.gif` file in my Typescript React app saying like below.

```
./src/gif/moving.gif 1:6
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

I have added some configuration in my  webpack setting after downloaded "file-loader"

```
{
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
    }, 
// new setting for gif loader
    {
      test: /\.(gif|svg|jpg|png)$/,
      loader: "file-loader",
    },
```

Any reason why I am still getting configuration error?

Answer (score 0):

There is https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-images that could fix your problem.   Otherwise you need to do it like so:

```jsx
import Image from 'next/image'

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Image
        src="/src/gif/moving.gif"
        alt="Moving Image"
        width={500}
        height={500}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Note: you can do `const movingGif = "/src/gif/moving.gif"` and then in the Image component `src={movingGif}`

Comment: importing next-images didn't work - the way importing `next.image` also doesn't work since the error says `gif` is type `string` and `Type '{ src: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ImageProps'.` Any reason why my GIF is recognized as string?

Comment: `src= "{gif}"` should work